# How to extract H s and V from an HSV image separately

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, colors

I am trying to extract H S and V channels from an HSV image [1x3] to convert it into linear space, somehow i am not able to extract it or at least at the end when i plot my a,b,c in the end i get a cube where as i expect a cone.

```
    %hsvToLinearSpace
% Converts a color from Matlab's HSV cube to a linear space (i.e. a cone)
%
%Inputs:
% colorsHsv - [1x3] color in Matlab's HSV space
%
%Outputs:
% colorLinear - [1x3] color in a linear space where Euclidean distances can
% be applied.
function colorLinear=hsvToLinearSpace(colorHsv)
    %---Modify this code---%
    colorLinear(1) = colorHsv(1);
    colorLinear(2) = colorHsv(2);
    colorLinear(3) = colorHsv(3);
    a=colorHsv(2)*colorHsv(3)*cos(2*pi*colorHsv(1));
    b=colorHsv(2)*colorHsv(3)*sin(2*pi*colorHsv(1));
    c=colorHsv(3);

    %----------------------%
end
```

Comment: You are calculating `a`, `b` and `c` in your function but not returning them, so you can't use them. What is the purpose of `colorLinear`, since it is the same as `colorHsv` and not changed at all?

Comment: Looks like you will have to do your homework after all.